# Emailing from an app

Tags: iphone, ios, email, sdk

i was just wondering how do you add the button and coding for emailing a page from your app... for example how do you add the button with an arrow in it for exporting/emailing [<-] and how do you use that to send something from a view... for example the screen may look like this.

stuff i wrote... blah blah blah

[<-]

then ur email comes up with your document attached

because I'm trying to add this button so that i could send a page people type on and then can send to themselves. i need to know how to develop and code that... thank you!

Comment: checkout sharekit (http://getsharekit.com/)

Answer (score 3):

This will display the "send mail" page within your app:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

MFMailComposeViewController *c = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
c.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[c setSubject:@"Subject"];
[c setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fred@example.com"]];
[c setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"joe@exmaple.com"]];
[c setMessageBody:@"Hello via email.  \n -me" isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated:YES]
```

see the docs for [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info,

add the `MessageUI` framework to your project

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:<your mailto: scheme>];`

Comment: would this pull up your email just like in the video on the home screen here... (getsharekit.com) start at 1:16

Comment: This will open the mail application, you can pass in title, body etc.

Answer (score 0):

An app can launch the email client in compose mode and the address already filled out.

The format of this URI should be familiar to anyone that has done any work with HTML and looks like this:

mailto://${EMAIL_ADDRESS}

For example, here I am opening the email application and filling the “to:” address with abc@xyz.com :

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://abc@xyz.com"]];
```